# Detecting repeated CURL (or other agent) requests

Tags: php, curl

If a user is using a browser, you can use sessions and cookies to more-or-less monitor user activity. Among other things, you can track repeated requests, such as login attempts.

If the user is using something like CURL, is there anyway to detect repeated requests?

I’m not worried so much abut DOS attacks, but more curious about attempts at breaking in.

I would be using PHP at the server end, and I am interested only in a PHP solution, rather than additional software.

Of course, the answer may be no …

Comment: The easiest solution is probably to just use the IP of the user, any reason why that wouldn't work?

Comment: @MatsLindh as far as I am aware, if multiple users are on the same private network using NAT, they would all appear to the server as having the same IP address.

Comment: They would, but that's usually where you'd present them with a captcha to solve, then set a session value that tells you they've identified themselves as a human. You can also use a fairly decent rate limit based on what you're trying to do. Otherwise the User-Agent string is probably your best bet, but anyone doing anything serious would fake that to a recent browser.

Comment: @MatsLindh I don’t think any of that would work if they’re using CURL, though.

Comment: If they are brute forcing a login we assume they are also proving an email or username? Use that. Count login attempts in say a database. Throttle / block as prescribed.

Comment: @Manngo .. which is the point, isn't it? If they can't verify the captcha, they won't be allowed access. You track the IP, and for _valid clients_ accept them after solving the captcha. This is how Google limits suspect clients (but they have a larger set of signals than just the IP, such as traffic compared to regular traffic patterns, etc.).

Comment: @ficuscr If they’re brute-forcing a password, that’s true. However, if they’re brute-forcing an email address, that assumption won’t work.

Comment: @MatsLindh I’ve always considered captcha as a way of punishing the innocent for the crimes of the guilty. In particular, Google’s captcha is all about getting ordinary users to sort out their self-driving AI for them. In any case, I know how to track requests coming fro a browser, and my question is specifically about tracking requests from non browser agents.